# MySQL combine multiple columns data to 1 column

Tags: mysql, multiple-columns

I want to combine multiple columns data into one column.

## for example:

This is the table structure I have:

```
[Color], [Size] , [Other]
White  , 23"x22", something
Black  , 22"x44", test
```

This is what I want to achieve:

```
[Other_Attributes]
color=White,size=23"x22",other=something
color=Black,size=22"x44",other=test
```

How can I achieve that with MYSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would help

```
select CONCAT('color=',Color,',size=', Size, ',other=', Other) concat_col 
From Tbl
```